# Открытие формы по центру другой формы

Tags: c#, wpf

Как в `WPF` открыть форму, которая была бы по центру родительской формы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Назначим главное окно хозяином второго окна (если не задано) и зададим открытие второго окна по центру хозяина

```
ownedWindow.Owner = this;
ownedWindow.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
```

Чуть полнее:

```
Window ownedWindow = new Window();
ownedWindow.Owner = this;
ownedWindow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
ownedWindow.Width = 100;
ownedWindow.Height = 100;
ownedWindow.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
```

Answer (score 4):

Для того, что бы окно открывалось по центру родителя, в `XAML` разметке окна нужно установить свойство `WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"`.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"

    // Открыть по центру
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"

    Title="MainWindow" />
```

P.S. Как справедливо заметил @AGS17, при установке свойства `WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"` через разметку `XAML` может возникнуть вопрос, а каким образом при таком подходе задается свойство `Owner`. На своей практике, данную задачу я обычно решаю реализацией сервиса по открытию модальных/диалоговых окон, данный сервис в простейшем случае имеет следующий интерфейс:

```
interface IWindowService
{
    bool? Show(ViewModelBase vm);

    bool? ShowDialog(ViewModelBase vm);
}
```

методы `Show(ViewModelBase vm)` и `ShowDialog(ViewModelBase vm)` принимают `VM`, для которой отображают соответствующую ей `View`. Поиск нужной `View` обычно осуществляется на основании `name convention`, например, для модели представления `UserViewModel` сервис будет искать представление `UserView`.
Соответственно после того как нужная `View` найдена у нее выставляется `Owner` и `DataContext`. Важно добавить, что реализация подобного сервиса отнимает время, поэтому чаще всего я использую готовые решения, которые уже предлагают из коробки WPF-Framework'и, например [Catel](http://catelproject.com/).

Comment: А задать `Owner`?

Comment: @AGS17 обычно я для этих целей реализую либо сервис по открытию модальных/диалоговых окон, данный сервис в большинстве случаев имеет метод `Show(ViewModelBase vm)` и `ShowDialog(ViewModelBase vm)`. Как можно заметить данные методы принимают `VM`, затем на ее основании отображают нужную `View`, соответственно при открытии `View` выставляется для нее родитель. Второй вариант, можно не заморачиваться с написанием сервисов и использовать какой-нибудь WPF-Framework, где эти сервис уже реализованы.

Comment: так вы это добавьте в ответ.

Comment: @AGS17 обновил ответ.